# How to avoid function wrap when passing a callback

Tags: javascript, oop, backbone.js

I would like to do pass a function to backbone's success callback like this

```
this.model.fetch({
    success: this.setup
});
```

However, that won't work I end up having to pass the whole environment and wrap inside a function like that:

```
var that = this;
this.model.fetch({
    success: function(){
        that.setup();
    }
});
```

Why can't I do this? Even if I bind the setup function to it's parent like so `_.bind( this.setup, this );`, it still won't use the proper this (its' parent). But only if its' not wrapped in a function...

Comment: `_.bind` should work for first code snippet

Comment: doesn't, had explained that. But apparently, bindall just works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_.bind` returns a function bound to an object, it does not modify the original function (basically it creates the wrapped function you wrote).

However, you could pass this bound function as a callback

```
this.model.fetch({
    success: _.bind(this.setup, this);
});
```

or use [`_.bindAll`](http://underscorejs.org/#bindAll) which does modify the object to use bound functions:

```
var V = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, "setup");

        this.model.fetch({
            success: this.setup
        });
    },
    setup: function() {

    }
});
```

Comment: I really needed to know the difference between those two functions and what they do exactly. Thanks for pointing me into the right direction!

Comment: @nimrod _.bind creates a new function where the binding is guaranteed, _.bindAll modifies an object (the first argument) to replace all member functions (or the ones passed as arguments) with a bound function. Take a look at the annotated source, it's mostly readable http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-58

Answer (score -1):

it does not work beacuse "this" is the object you are defining ({ success: this.setup }) try this:

```
var that = this;
this.model.fetch({
      success: that.setup
    }
});
```

however, i dont like it too much, since event handlers are just that, they handle events, and then do stuff (like setup() method) also, in this case, you may lost object in the closure.

Comment: that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid which I said in my question, not ver helpful answer sorry.